# Conditions for four real and distinct roots of a quartic

Tags: inequality, roots, discriminant, quartics

I am trying to find the range of values for $m$ such that the equation $n^4-2n^2m-6n^2+2m^2-2m=0$ will have 4 real and distinct roots. My approach so far has been:

Let $u=n^2$ (I feel that this substitution shouldn't make a difference as I'm not trying to find the specific roots of $n$)

$ \implies u^2-2um-6u+2m^2-2m$ = 0

$ \implies u^2+(-2m-6)u+(2m^2-2m)$ = 0

Using the quadratic discriminant $b^2-4ac$, I obtain:

$(-2m-6)^2 - (4)(1)(2m^2-2m) > 0 $

$ \implies -4m^2+32m+36>0$

$ \implies m^2-8m-9<0 $

$ \implies (m-9)(m+1)<0 $

$ \implies -1<m<9 $

All of this seemed fine to me, however the answer appears to be $-1<m<0$ AND $1<m<9$. In effect, my inequality is correct except between 0 and 1 inclusive. The only way I found this out was by graphing the original equation. How can I derive the correct inequalities ALGEBRAICALLY?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be
$$2m+6>0,$$ $$2m^2-2m>0$$ and $$(m+3)^2-(2m^2-2m)>0.$$

Let $n^2=x$.

Hence, we need to find all values of $m$ for which the equation
$$x^2-2(m+3)x+2m^2-2m=0$$ has two positive roots.

The quadratic equation $ax^2+bx+c=0$ has positive roots $x_1$ and $x_2$ iff
$$x_1+x_2=-\frac{b}{a}>0,$$  $$x_1x_2=\frac{c}{a}>0$$ and $$\Delta=b^2-4ac>0.$$

Comment: Should be $2m+6>0$. Also $m+3$ not $m-3$

Comment: The original problem was changed.

Comment: Oh dear, I thought I had edited the post (to correct a typo) quickly enough but to his immense credit Michael Rozenberg answered virtually as soon as I had posted it, explaining why he has different answers! Many thanks to both of you: this clearly works! However, I'm still not understanding how these inequalities were derived to begin with. Could someone kindly explain? Thanks very much in advance!

Comment: @NKRsolutions I added something. See now.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg This is very elegant and neat: I had neglected that the quadratic needed to have roots which were strictly POSITIVE as well as real and distinct. Thanks a lot for your instructive and very quick help here!